# Implement Android layout TableView

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have to represent the data in this way:

- How can I implement this?
- can I have some advice for starting with the implementation?
- Do you know any example that already exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I have more than one list. And in the Custom List view I can only pass a list.

You can pass more than 1 list if you make an adapter constructor that accepts more lists as parameters.
Something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context context;
List<String> data1999;
List<String> data2005;
List<String> data2008;

public STHAdapter(Context context, List<String> data1999, List<String> data2005, List<String> data2008) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data1999=data1999;
    this.data2005=data2005;
    this.data2008=data2008;

}

View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

...
TextView txt1999 = convertView.findViewByID(...yourID);
TextView txt2005 = convertView.findViewByID(...yourID);
TextView txt2008 = convertView.findViewByID(...yourID);

txt1999.setText(""+data1999.get(position));

txt2005.setText(""+data2005.get(position));

txt2008.setText(""+data2008.get(position));



}
```

If you have 3 lists and in every list you input data for the following year.
Then, in your custom cell, you make 3 textViews, that will show data for three years you have.

For every cell, you will populate textView with the data fetchet from the position you are currently in.

Comment: ok just that I was looking for. 
And when I implement this method: 

"View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {}" 

how do I manage three lists?

Comment: Thanks you are very kind. 

But if the three lists have different size? It does not create any problems?

Comment: It will be a problem. In that case, dont just make a list of strings, but make a list of objects instead. Every object should have id and value. That value can be null then, if there is no data for that specific event. So that way, you wont have an error but you can write something like "no data" in your table

Comment: ok thanks, you gave me a great idea. This is exactly what I was trying to understand. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way too broad to be answered here.
But here is a nice tutorial on custom ListView to get you started.

[ListView Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

After you mastered what is done there, you can move on and make your own custom List, however you need it to look like.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. 

This I can do :) 

The problem is that I have more than one list. And in the Custom List view I can only pass a list.

Comment: As I said, you can make custom list.
Every cell of the list can have 4 TextViews.  1 of them can be whatever name you need and other three some value, for 3 different years, as I can see on the picture you provided.
SO, my advice for you is to first learn about basic ListView in Android and then follow a detailed tutorial on custom list view adapters. After you successfully finish those two, you will be able to make something like this

Comment: OK, I will follow your advice (: